# Remove noise / artifacts from single colour raster logo (Gimp)

Tags: gimp, logo, raster, noise

I hope this is not a duplicate question - I have looked at other answers and I'm convinced this is different enough for its own question.

[image]

I have a single-colour logo in raster format that I need to clean up. The above image shows what the rest of the image is like; the above has the finest detail though, so I thought I'd show that part of it.

I am using GIMP. I have played around with its colour tools, such as desaturate, threshold, curves, but I cannot seem to clean it up as well as I expected to be able. The best results I've achieved so far were no better than the original.

Is there a best-practice method for this? Are my methods in the right ballpark? Is GIMP just as capable as photoshop for this, or do I really need photoshop?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated as an answer, but maybe a useful tip for others hitting here: never save logos or line art as ".jpg" files - this kindo f noise is intriduced automatically. If you need raster images use PNG.

Answer (score 3):

I've just come up with something which is somewhat better than the original:

Step 1: Resize to 200%

Step 2: Colour -> Desaturate > By lightness

Step 3: Colour-> Curves:

[image]

Step 4: Colour -> Colourize

Step 5: Resize to 50% (i.e. back to 100% of original)

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the logo is the same color, you can use the **Select By Color Tool**([image: Select by color tool]).

1. Choose the **Select By Color Tool** then click and drag on an orange part until all of the orange is covered.

[image: Make selection]

2. Copy(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) the selection and make a new layer from it and put a white filled layer underneath it.

[image: Orange separated from background]

After this, you can then clean up the orange a bit more as you did in your answer.